# How to sumif only negative numbers from a filtered range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data that has negative numbers in a single column.

[image: Desired Outcome Layout]

To sum negative numbers in the column, I am using the following formula.
`=SUMIF(Total Range,"<0")`

I also need to include sum of negative numbers if the range was filtered. Somewhat like using the below, but with added condition of "<0".
`=SUBTOTAL(9,Total Range)`

I tried using SUMIFS, but there is no criteria available for a call being visible. Any suggestions? I have been restricted from using VBA, and I cannot add a helper column (I thought of creating a helper column to convert all positives to 0 and then use Subtotal, the proposal was rejected because additional columns on the data set can cause other issues).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: One possible way could be like this: `=SUM(MAP(Range,LAMBDA(x,SUBTOTAL(103,x)))*(Range<0)*Range)`

Comment: `=REDUCE(0,Total Range, Lambda(a,b,a+SUBTOTAL(9,b)*(b<0)))`

Comment: What logic are you using to hide the rows? Can you add that as a condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(IF(SUBTOTAL(103, OFFSET(Total Range, ROW(Total Range) - MIN(ROW(Total Range)),,1)), IF(Total Range<0, Total Range, 0), 0))
```

The logic behind the formular is,

1. OFFSET(Total Range, ROW(Total Range) - MIN(ROW(Total Range)),,1) creates an array that references each cell in your Total Range individually.
2. SUBTOTAL(103, ...) returns an array of 1s and 0s, where 1 represents a visible cell and 0 represents a hidden cell.
3. The outer IF statement checks if each cell's value in Total Range is negative, and if so, it includes that in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the answer of Ugochukwu Obinna, which I believe works perfectly, you could also use the following, which is maybe just slightly more efficient:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(Total Range,ROW(Total Range)-MIN(ROW(Total Range)),,1)),--(Total Range<0))
```

Or the same with less typing :)

```
=SUM(SUBTOTAL(109,OFFSET(Total Range,ROW(Total Range)-MIN(ROW(Total Range)),,1))*--(Total Range<0))
```